# QML/Qt native window is overlapping / hiding popups

Tags: qt, qml

I am currently transitioning a user interface from traditional Qt Widgets to QML. This includes a rather complicated 3D viewer derived from QOpenGLWidget. I would like to avoid porting this for now. What I did instead was embedding the separate viewer window into my UI. If I am not wrong, this is called "native window" (or used for such). The code looks like this:

```c
auto qml_window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(m_qml_app_engine->rootObjects().first());
QWindow* viewer_window = QWindow::fromWinId(m_viewer->winId());
viewer_window->setParent(qml_window);
```

The viewer embedded window is then coupled to a QQuickItem with the following anchor class:

```
class WidgetAnchor: public QObject
{
public:
  WidgetAnchor(QWidget* widget, QQuickItem* item)
      : QObject(widget), m_widget(widget), m_quick_item(item)
  {
    connect(m_quick_item, &QQuickItem::xChanged,      this, &WidgetAnchor::updateGeometry);
    connect(m_quick_item, &QQuickItem::yChanged,      this, &WidgetAnchor::updateGeometry);
    connect(m_quick_item, &QQuickItem::widthChanged,  this, &WidgetAnchor::updateGeometry);
    connect(m_quick_item, &QQuickItem::heightChanged, this, &WidgetAnchor::updateGeometry);
    updateGeometry();
  }
private:
  QPointer<QWidget>    m_widget;
  QPointer<QQuickItem> m_quick_item;

  void updateGeometry()
  {
    if (m_quick_item)
    {
      QRectF r = m_quick_item->mapRectToItem(
          0,
          QRectF(m_quick_item->x(), m_quick_item->y(), m_quick_item->width(), m_quick_item->height()));
      m_widget->setGeometry(r.toRect());
    }
  }
};
```

It all works pretty good, although I am aware people are warning not to mix QML and QWidgets. The only real downside I noticed is that popups (including combo boxes etc.) from QML will now appear behind the embedded window. I have tried raise/lower, force foreground/background, but no solution is really working. Either the viewer completely disappears or popups do.

Does anyone with more insights know whats happening? And is there a solution to it, or is this something I have to live with?